# User switch between layers in Tilemill

Tags: mapping, layer, tilemill

I'm completely new to TileMill, so please excuse my ignorance and any easy solutions I've missed. I'm working on a map of local fire responses and response times, and I'd like to be able to switch between layers (displaying one at a time), like this map -- http://graphics.latimes.com/how-fast-is-lafd/#10/34.0504/-118.6002

From what I gather, this isn't something that TileMill can do on the front end. Am I missing something? Is there a good work around?

Answer (score 1):

> From what I gather, this isn't something that TileMill can do on the front end.

That's correct: this is something you would use [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/) to do. TileMill is a map design tool, so it is great at creating tiles and designs, but it is not the tool you would use to create a user interface like a layer switcher.